# matplotlib basemap hexbin colorbar maximum value higher than maximum value in array

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm using *matplotlib* and *basemap* to draw some maps. What I'm doing is diaplying some spatial data with **hexbin** function.

Also, I'm generating a sequence of maps that contain that same data over different periods of time.

The problem is that as data is accumulated over time - maximum value of a histogram is increasing. I don't use C input:

```
hb = m.hexbin(my_data[:ct + 1, 1], my_data[:ct + 1, 0], mincnt=1, cmap='summer')
```

Is it possible to keep the maximum value of a colorbar relatively high so that points that are drawn on the map change their colours, say from green(very low) to yellow(very high)? At the same time yellow colour would correspond to a very high value that will never be accumulated during hexbin drawings?

Hope I was clear enough. If not - please, let me know. I'll try to approach to the problem description in a different way. Sorry again for this mess in a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the `vmax` argument in hexbin. Here's some example code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.linspace(1, 100, 1000)
y = x
plt.hexbin(x, y, mincnt = 1, gridsize = 16, vmax = 100, cmap='summer')
```

Here's what it looks like when I don't use vmax:[image: Hexbin plot without vmax]

And here's the same plot with vmax:
[image: Hexbin plot with vmax]